# overlapping js datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, laravel-blade

I'm trying to get a date picker working using the following external library and example -

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

blade code:

```
 {!! Form::text('date',null, array('id' => 'datepicker','required',        'class'=>'form-control')) !!}
```

Script:

```
<script>
 $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

[please see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7btP5.png)

Comment: use z-index for datepicker and addhaar no. So, when you open datepicker it will come front.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your style-

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
           z-index:99999999;
}
```

and set the z-index of 'Aadhar No.' field to 0